# Are Xcode 4 and iOS SDK 4.3 compatible with Snow Leopard?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Currently I am using Xcode 3 and iOS SDK 4.2 on Snow Leopard. I am planning to download and install Xcode 4 and iOS SDK 4.3.

I would like to know if Xcode 4 and iOS SDK 4.3 are compatible with Snow Leopard.

Comment: Reinforcing the comments below, even if you are targeting an older version of iOS as your build target, you should still use the iOS SDK 5.0, ehich comes with Xcode 4.2.

Comment: Yes. There is a Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard. I should upgrade to Xcode 4.2 and iOS SDK 5.0 rather than Xcode 4 and iOS SDK 4.3.

Comment: Definitely. Some of the new features (e.g. automatic reference counting) are backwards compatible with older versions of iOS. Any features that are not backwards compatible are not used if you set iOS 4.2 (or whatever) as your build target.

Comment: I am using Xcode 3.2.4 and sdk 4.2. File size of Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard is 1.6 GB. I think is an upgrade for sdk 4. Is there any upgrade for Xcode 3.2.4 before installing Xcode 4.2 or just install Xcode 4.2?

Answer (score 5):

Yes..You will have separate .dmg available for download when you visit iOS developer center X-Code download link.

Please do note that the **X-Code 4.2 will have iOS 5 simulator and library** only. If you want lower version simulator and library with X-Code just goto **X.Code->Prefrences-> Downloads Tab.** In downloads tab you'll have two tabs:

**1) Components** - Here you will have option to download iOS 4.3 simulator(~600 Mb), iOS 4.0-4.1(~670 MB) Device debugging support, iOS 3.0-3.2.2(686.3 MB) Device debugging support.

**2) Documentation-** Yoy will have option to download iOS 5.0,XCode 4.2 Developer libaray,Mac OSX 10.7 Core Library.

[image]

Install the components which ever you need and there you go..

Hope that helps.

Comment: There is no XCode 4.3 download for Snow Leopard

Answer (score 4):

There's a specific version of Xcode 4.2 (and likely earlier versions) that can be used on Snow Leopard. That's the version I use on my iMac. Note that you can use 4.2 w/iOS5 SDK and still deploy on older devices (and even download the 4.3 simulator) in case you cannot find Xcode 4.

However you cannot use (download) the one from the AppStore which is Lion-specific. To find the Snow Leopard specific version log into Apple's developers portal and you'll see separate links for SL and Lion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's compatible.  Download the XCode 4.2 .dmg from the iOS dev program portal, which includes the iOS 5.0 SDK.

http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_with_ios_5_sdk/xcode_4.2_and_ios_5_sdk_for_snow_leopard.dmg

Comment: Thank you so much David. I am downloading now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only if you have the correct download from Apple.

There are currently 2 separate dmg downloads for the SDK and Xcode installer from the enrolled Developer web site, one for Lion and one for Snow Leopard.  The download for Lion is only compatible with Lion.  The download for Snow Leopard is only compatible with Snow Leopard.  The installer from the App store might be for Lion only, so you may have to sign up for the developer program to get the other installer.

Apple usually removes (or hides) downloads for previous versions of the SDK, so if you didn't download the correct installer dmg (with the SDK for iOS 4.x) for the Mac OS of interest in time, you won't have a compatible installer.